# REACT: On render, give each div a unique className

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have been working on a photo gallery app and set up the basic structure using HTML and CSS. **Now, I want to render the photos using React**, but I could not give each div that contains the photos a unique className ( I want to set 1st photo className="item item-1" 2nd photo className=item item-2" and so on). I am new to coding and especially unexperienced with React, so all advices would help a lot!

**On PhotoItem.jsx, how can I add the this.key value to the className?**

**Also, is the current structure of rendering(index.jsx -> App.jsx -> PhotoList.jsx -> PhotoItem.jsx) okay?**

This is the structure that I want to replicate (which I made using only HTML and CSS).
[image: This]

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="photos">
    Hello World
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my styles.css:

```
#photos-gallery {
  height: 275px;
  width: 634px;
}

.photos-gallery-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  color: #333;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  justify-content: space-between;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin: 0 0 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.photos-gallery-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 50% 15% 15%;
  grid-column-gap: 0;
  grid-row-gap: 0;
  height: 200px;
}   

.photos-gallery-content .item {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.photos-gallery-content .item-1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 1;
}

.photos-gallery-content .item-2 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 1;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

.photos-gallery-content .item-3 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: span 3;
}
```

Here is my index.jsx:

```
import App from './components/App.jsx'

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('photos'));
```

Here is my App.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import PhotoList from './PhotoList.jsx';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      photos: [
        "https://i.imgur.com/8pTwPlXb.jpg",
        "https://i.imgur.com/OPAR3PCb.jpg",
        "https://i.imgur.com/A8eQsll.jpg",
        "https://i.imgur.com/2cGhWubb.jpg",
        "https://i.imgur.com/KhYHiPYb.jpg",
        "https://i.imgur.com/1KSodpOb.jpg",
        "https://i.imgur.com/WdlOxaxb.jpg",
        "https://i.imgur.com/ZtHebw9b.jpg",
        "https://i.imgur.com/oqJCGvTb.jpg"

      ]
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="photos-gallery">
        <h2 className="photos-gallery-header"> 9 Photos </h2>
        <PhotoList photos={this.state.photos} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is my PhotoList.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import PhotoItem from './PhotoItem.jsx';

var PhotoList = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="photos-gallery-content">
      {props.photos.map(photo => 
        <PhotoItem key={props.photos.indexOf(photo)} photo={photo} />
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
export default PhotoList;
```

Here is my PhotoItem.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

const PhotoItem = ({photo}) => {
  return (
    <div className='item item-`${this.key}`'>
      <div className='photo'>
        <img src={photo} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};
export default PhotoItem;
```

Comment: Also note that you can't use `this` keyword with functional react components.

Answer (score 2):

`this.key` doesn't have any meaning. Just pass the index into the component as a prop and use that.

```
{ props.photos.map((photo, index) =>
  <PhotoItem key={index} index={index} photo={photo} />
)}
```

--

```
const PhotoItem = ({index, photo}) => {
  return (
    <div className='item item-`${index}`'>
      <div className='photo'>
        <img src={photo} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When I check the Element panel, it still shows <div class="item item-`${index}`"> instead of <div class="item item-1>. I thought using `${}` would display the value of the index, but it is not and I am a bit confused.

Comment: sorry, replace `<div className='item item-\`${index}\`'>` with `div className={\`item item-${index}\`}>`

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. React team decided to not allow users to make use of react-specific props such as `key` and `ref`.

You can read more about it here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2429

So use another prop name like `index`(as suggested by Tyler) or `className` itself.

```
<PhotoItem key={index} className={index} photo={photo} />
```

---

```
const PhotoItem = ({className, photo}) => {
   return (
      <div className={`item item-${className}`}>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When I check the Element panel, it still shows <div class="item item-`${index}`"> instead of <div class="item item-1>. I thought using `${}` would display the value of the index, but it is not and I am a bit confused.

Comment: @MichaelLee There was an issue with the template-literal syntax you were using. Updated the answer to reflect the correct way.